# Using Javascript to do browser actions

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, browser

So, a while back I wrote a script in Python to automatically register me to classes in my school (by creating a browser with mechanize and signing in with my user/password and clicking the buttons etc) 
lately I've been trying to learn JavaScript/html/css and I was thinking JavaScript would be better suited for such stuff, but I don't really understand the concept of how it will work yet, because the only way I've seen JavaScript used is linked from an html file and then run when you load the html.

I was wondering how would I create a standalone JavaScript to do those kind of stuff without html and how would I run it? (Do I download an interpreter of some kind?)

I could find information about that kind of stuff through Googling though i'm sure it's there I just don't know what this is called (tried web mining and web crawling but it doesn't seem to be it)

Comment: Bookmarklets or browser extensions/userscripts.

Comment: What about using Node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, wrong use. If you are going to try to use JS externally to manipulate a browser page, you are going to have to open a web console on your browser then paste the code in, which is totally impractical.

Node.js does let one write Javascript that has full file system access, etc. to your computer, so this would be your best bet, but your question is pretty vague so I can't tell if this is exactly what you would need.